# Is the question in the Munkres's topology book wrong?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

At the end of cheapter $8.1$,

$4)$ Given spaces $X$ and $Y$, let $[X,Y]$ denote the set of homotopy classes of maps of $X$ into $Y$.

$b)$ Show that if $Y$ is path connected, the set $[I,Y]$ has a single element.($I=[0,1]$)

---

### **Claim$1:$**

If $Y$ contains a hole then the loop containing the hole can not be homotopic to the ones which is not containing. So is it wrong ?

---

### **Claim$2:$**

Beside that, when I first try to prove the claim,

Let $f:I\to Y$ be a continious map. Set $$F:I\times I\to Y$$

$$(x,t)\mapsto f(x(1-t)) $$

Then $f$ is homotopic to a constant map. As $Y$ is path connected all constant map is homotopic to each other. Thus we are done.

---

But I am not sure about niether of them.

Comment: The definition of $[I, Y]$ does not require end points to be fixed, unlike the case with the fundamental group. This is a crucial difference.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: So, Is my second claim is true ?

Comment: Yes, your second claim is true/the proof is correct.

Comment: @k.stm: But I stil can not see the why the firstone is wrong. Ca n you explain it ?

Comment: @mesel AymanHourieh already explained it. Look up the definition of $[X,Y]$ in Munkres and then compare $[I,Y]$ to the definition of the fundamental group given in the book. (I don’t know the book, but I’m very certain that he’ll be right.) If you still think there’s a conflict, you should cite the definitions.

Comment: @Brahadeesh: I asked this question in 2015, the link which you give in 2018. Which one is duplicate of other?

Comment: @mesel See [this meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8740/279515), especially [Zev Chonoles' answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8742/279515). Since you received an answer three years ago, you could have answered your own question and marked it as accepted. That way any new duplicates can be linked to your question. It is not possible to link a duplicate to an unanswered question. I will be quite happy to reverse my vote to close as duplicate if this question is answered.

Comment: @Brahadeesh: Under the claim 2, there is a suggested answer. I was just not sure about it. If you read the comments, it is n correct answer. By this sense, they are not even same question. I could have solved the problem, I just thought that claim 1 and claim 2 contradicts with each other and what am I missing? This was all about.

Comment: @mesel The asker of the question I linked has the same confusion, only phrased differently, as I see it. So, I don't agree that `they are not even the same question`. Yes, your post is answered in the comments, but it is good policy to convert such comments into a proper answer. Would you like to write an answer to take this question off the unanswered list? I can also upvote and reverse my vote to close as duplicate, then.